# How to resolve 'System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate'

Tags: systemd

When I use this command:

```
root:~# systemctl
```

Output is:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate
```

This problem occurred in "Kali Linux" and "Debian 9"
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: That means that the system is running with `sysvinit` rather than systemd. What are you trying to do? *I.e.*, what do you need to use `systemctl` for?

Comment: @StephenKitt I would like to start any package with systemctl, like: systectl openvas start

Comment: OK, but why specifically with `systemctl`?

Comment: A package might contain anything, there's no such concept called "start a package".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To start and stop services without having to worry about which init system is in use, you should use [`service`](https://manpages.debian.org/service):

```
service openvas start
```

will use whatever command is appropriate to start the `openvas` service.

Answer (score 3):

In Debian, this can be "fixed" by re-installing the [system-wide service supervision](https://packages.debian.org/buster/runit-systemd) package.

The following command installs the systemd integration package `runit-systemd` and will remove `sysvinit` in the process because the system can only have one:

```
apt-get install runit-systemd
```

Comment: No. `runit-systemd` is for transition from systemd to runit. 
If you want systemd to replace sysv, you should install `systemd-sysv`.
See `apt info runit-systemd` and `apt info systemd-sysv`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error in a Docker container, one solution for
that error: *"System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate."* in a Docker container is to run the container with more privileges.

To give the maximum of privileges (e.g. to fully manipulate the host from within the Docker container), [the `--privileged` command line argument exists](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#:%7E:text=The%20%2D%2Dprivileged%20flag%20gives,like%20running%20Docker%20within%20Docker.):

> The `--privileged` flag gives all capabilities to the container, and it also lifts all the limitations enforced by the device cgroup controller. In other words, the container can then do almost everything that the host can do. This flag exists to allow special use-cases, like running Docker within Docker.

E.g. To run systemd from within a container a pull image command could look like:

```
docker run -d --name "systemd_example_container" --privileged \
   -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-ubuntu:18.04
```

And to run an interactive shell inside the container, a command could look like:

```
docker exec -it "systemd_example_container" bash
```

Downside is that it requires the `--privileged` flag which may not be applicable for every docker runtime configuration, so take it with a grain of salt.

More information is available in [Running systemd in a non-privileged container (by *Daniel Walsh* for *Red Hat Developer*; 2016-09 updated 2019-04)](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container).