# System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Tags: systemd, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux the command I typed was

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.gz
```

and all i get is

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1).
Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I'm a noob but I am familiar with Kali Linux tho little bit

Comment: If you're not familiar with Linux systems in general then you'll have no end of problems with Kali. It's not designed to be general purpose - it's a specialist pentest system

Comment: that's why I'm leaning can you help me with this question I ask

Comment: I can't help you with Kali, no. But I can recommend you use a more user-centric distribution such as Mint, Ubuntu, or Fedora. Get familiar with one of those and then you'll handle Kali far more easily

Comment: how do id o that?

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440364/117549 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve 'System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440364/how-to-resolve-system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1)

Comment: yes jeff schaller

Comment: thanasisp i looked at that already i have tried almost everything

Comment: This thread explains @roaima's (and other's) responses: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/256455).  You won't have this problem if you use Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/Elementary/CentOS/Fedora/Manjaro/...

Comment: but i already stuck with it i mean i love it

Comment: @Stewart, it's not that I won't help, it's that I don't know the answer. But using a more general purpose distribution or more likely to work

Comment: @roaima:  Most of us don't know the answer, the rest of us don't feel years of understanding can be condensed into a few short laymen-understandable paragraphs. that's why OP can't get help.  Kali is its own beast and OP should understand the active init system.  Asking why a `systemctl` command doesn't work on `sysvinit` or wsl shows a fundamental misunderstanding and lack of prerequisite experience needed to run kali. If someone does answer, OP will probably just run into a different issue tomorrow (@roaima's first comment was right on point). OP should use a more beginner-friently distro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

im am using a windows subsystem kali linux fyi
i just deleted it and reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

if you are using WSL the problem is that these distributions do not use systemd use sysvinit you can check it using the command `ps -p 1 -o comm=` has to output something like init or sys.
the syntax is **`<name_of_service>  <comand>`**

Comment: yeah but how do i do what i want to do?

Comment: @Huperdragon you've not actually said anywhere in your question what it is that you want to do

Comment: hupdragon? this sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.gz .look at this link:https://www.tecmint.com/resolve-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution/

Comment: It might be a better idea to state your actual main problem (including information on your operating system). Is it name resolution? You can add what you've tried to do to solve it and the error you've found.

Comment: well emm I cant really  remember tho